# npm proxy settings escape '\' char

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm, escaping, special-characters

I am behind a corporate proxy and I need to set the settings to npm. The only problem is my username contains a `\` char. The proxy setting should look like this: `http://PREFIX\username:password@proxy.company.com:port` but the end result is like this: `http://prefix/username:password@proxy.company.com:port` which is totally wrong.

Putting `%5C` instead of `\` doesn't work. Neither does putting the username and password, or the whole url in `""`.

I know this question has been asked numerous times but none of the solutions did it for me. I am on a windows machine. I would be grateful if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

You have to [percent-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) | [encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the special characters. E.g. instead of this:

```
http://foo:B/r@domain.com:8080
```

you write this:

```
http://foo:B%2Fr@domain.com:8080
```

So `/` gets replaced with `%2F`.

Comment: Hi , the links given in the above answer already address. %25 will be the equivalent of % symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Use %5C, it will replace '\'

```
http://foo:T\abc@test.com:8080
```

to

```
http://foo:T%5Cabc@test.com:8080
```